# Получение текста из JTextArea содержащегося внутри JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

есть JScrollPane, который содержит в себе JTextArea. Необходимо получить текст из JTextArea, как это можно сделать?
Структура следующая:

```
    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(String.valueOf(res));
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(area);
    pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
  pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    choiceFile.addTab(workFile.getName(), pane);
    choiceFile.setSelectedIndex(i);
```

choiceFile - это JTabbedPane. JScrollPane - это скроллбар в который добавляется текст из JTextArea, который считался из выбранного пользователем файла. 
workFile - файл, который только что выбрал пользователь. res - строка,содержащая информацию считанную из файла.
Так как присутствует JTabbedPane, то JTextArea существует достаточно недолго (только внутри метода Open). Как можно получить текст из JScrollPane?
Выглядит все это следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

До этого, считывание текста происходило легко, так как JTabbedPane содержал JTextArea и происходило это так:

```
int j = 0;
String text = ((JTextArea)choiceFile.getComponentAt(choiceFile.getSelectedIndex())).getText();
JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setText(text);
int l = area.getLineCount();
ArrayList<String> allString = new ArrayList<>();
String allText = text;
for (String buffer : allText.split("\n")) {
    allString.add(buffer);
}
while (j < allString.size()) {
    out.append(allString.get(j) + "\r\n");
    j++;
}
```

Где out - это BufferedWriter содержащий информацию о том, куда необходимо записать полученную информацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось сделать следующим образом

```
JTextArea c = (JTextArea) (((JViewportView) (((JScrollPane) choiceFile.getComponentAt(choiceFile.getSelectedIndex())).getViewport()))).getView();
```